# Parse through list in python for string that starts with certain characters and is length N

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I tried to emulate this
[Find strings of length 10 with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427107/find-strings-of-length-10-with-regex)

with this

```
for char in updated_metabolite:
    found_all = re.findall('^cpd.{5}$', updated_metabolite)
```

the list updated_metabolites looks like this before running the above code:

```
cpd00001;cpd00009;cpd00015;cpd00041;cpd00095;cpd00982;cpd02333
cpd00001;cpd00003;cpd00004;cpd00067;cpd00075;cpd00985
cpd00003;cpd00004;cpd00067;cpd15560;cpd15561
cpd00005;cpd00006;cpd00067;cpd14938;cpd17051
cpd00001;cpd00002;cpd00003;cpd00004;cpd00008;cpd00009;cpd00067;cpd00149;cpd03913;cpd03914
cpd00005;cpd00006;cpd11669;cpd17097
cpd00005;cpd00006;cpd00067;cpd00129;cpd02431
cpd00001;cpd00015;cpd00067;cpd00129;cpd00858;cpd00982
cpd00005;cpd00006;cpd00011;cpd00017;cpd00060;cpd00067;cpd00791;cpd02083;cpd03091;
```

Comment: I don't know what your question is, but it is peculiar that you are running the `findall` in a loop, particularly since you do not use `char`.

Comment: The problem with using `.{5}` is that this matches 5 of *any* character, so if you had `cpd067;cpd00129;` then the first match would be `cpd067;c`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use beginning and end of line anchors (`^` and `$`) because in your file there are multiple matches in the same line:

```
re.findall(r'cpd\d{5}', updated_metabolite)
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is create a list out of semicolon-separated data, you should use `re.split` instead.

```
lst = re.split(';|\n', updated_metabolite)
```

#### Output

```
['cpd00001', 'cpd00009', 'cpd00015', ...]
```

Comment: `re.split('[;\n]',` is equally valid

Comment: Thank you, sorry to change the question a bit, but how would I separate this data? As you can see it is one big string. -- >: (1) cpd00015_c + (1) cpd00041_c + (1) cpd00095_c <=> (2) cpd00001_c + (1) cpd00009_c + (1) cpd00982_c + (1) cpd02333_c
(3) cpd00004_c + (4) cpd00067_c + (1) cpd00075_c <= (1) cpd00001_c + (3) cpd00003_c + (1) cpd00985_c XXXXXXXXX

Comment: Find what the separator is.  If it is fixed then use `str.split`, if it requires a pattern then use `re.split`.

Comment: @user9995331 Please add this input example to your question and I will have a look at it